# I am not able to launch react app project

Tags: create-react-app, yarnpkg

I followed all the instructions from [https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWpjr.png) using yarn. For some reason when I am trying to launch the project yarn start, it gives me this error message

[image]

My node version is 8.16.0 and yarn -v 1.15.2. exactly what is required for creating the create react app. I do not have problem with creating the project, but I have with launching. Could you please help solving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well probably you have to install [events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/events) package.

`yarn add events` or `npm install events`

Should help :)